# How to copy directory name to variable in Windows command prompt?

Tags: command-line

I tried to do so by using `findstr` on `%cd%` but couldn't find a way to do so without using a file to process. And the g:/ option seems to mean `findstr` runs interactively and cannot be piped into. So without using files is there a way?

Comment: You’ll have to explain a little more; it is not quite clear what you are trying to do or what the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to set a variable to contain the name of the parent of the current directory (in a `.cmd` file):

```
for %%i in (.) do set parent=%%~dpi
echo parent %parent%
```

See `help for` for more information on the tilde substitutions.

If you just want to set a variable to the current directory:

```
set dir=%cd%
```